# Print Bitmap image over multiple pages using PDFSharp, Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, bitmap, pdfsharp

I have a panel which draws a diagram based on user input. Unfortunately the diagrams can get really really big, and when I print them it doesn't entirely fit on a single page without losing readability.

I'm using PDFsharp within VB.net to create the PDF. The current method is the turn the panel in which the diagram is drawn on to a bitmap image, and then place the image in the pdf document.

1 diagram can easily make the panel 1500,3000 in size.

[Example of Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/romFP.png)

[Example of Diagram in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KnUf.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
        Dim pdfdoc As New PdfDocument
        Dim page As PdfPage = pdfdoc.AddPage
        Dim Bitmap As Bitmap = New Bitmap(pnl_Draw.Width, pnl_Draw.Height)
        Dim BXImage As XImage
        Dim GFX As XGraphics
        Me.pnl_Draw.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, New Rectangle(0, 0, Bitmap.Width, Height))
        Dim pbx As New PictureBox
        pbx.Image = Bitmap
        BXImage = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(pbx.Image)
        GFX = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page)
        GFX.ScaleTransform(0.82)
        GFX.DrawImage(BXImage, 0, 0)
        GFX.Dispose()
        pdfdoc.Save("G:\test.pdf")
        pdfdoc.Close()
        Try
            Process.Start("G:\test.pdf")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: in the Adobe Reader Print dialog click on "Poster" to print the image on more than 1 page. Increase the Zoom factor to distribute the poster on as many pages as you need.

You can also increase the page size proportionally to the bitmap size.

BTW: You don't need `GFX.ScaleTransform(0.82)` if you specify the destination size in the call to `GFX.DrawImage`.